# Sorting and RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, functional-programming, runtime-error

I've never learned functional programming but I was forced to implement own sorting algorithm in this paradigm.

This is my naive approach:

```
def sort(array):
    def step(idx, array):
        if idx == len(array)-1:
            return array
        if array[idx] > array[idx+1]:
            return step(0, array[0:idx] + [array[idx+1]] + [array[idx]]
                        + array[idx+2:len(array)])
        else: return step(idx+1, array)

    return step(0, array)
```

And for arrays with size under 21 everything works fine. But when `len(array)` is 21 (or bigger of course) I got, quite often but not always, `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

I've tried functional quicksort implementation founded on Internets and it works great even for million-elements arrays. It's preaty clear that I've done something wrong but, because I don't have any experience in functional programming, I don't know where the problem is. Any help?

**Quicksort:**

```
def qsort(L):
    return (qsort([y for y in L[1:] if y <  L[0]]) + 
            L[:1] + 
            qsort([y for y in L[1:] if y >= L[0]])) if len(L) > 1 else L
```

Comment: You don't really want to be writing a recursive sort algorithm in Python - it doesn't natively support tail recursion optimisation hence your stack exploding - not to mention it's remarkably inefficient... Are the other implementations also in Python you've discovered?

Comment: I don't really care about efficiency because it's about an idea. I'm aware that Python isn't the best choice for that things. The problem is that the functional python quicksort implementation works great while mine sorting algorithm crashes for arrays bigger than 20. Why? What did I wrong?

Comment: What algorithm are you comparing it to that works? Does comparing the two give hints as to a key difference?

Comment: I've added this algorithm to my question.

Comment: Your algorithm recurses as soon as it finds an inversion. The quicksort you show splits the array in two subarrays and then recurses in both subarrays: the recursion depth is limited.

Comment: What should I change to make my algorithm better? I don't want just another quicksort implementation but to improve my own code.